# Getting sum of two rows in an inner joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, left-join, aggregate-functions

I have these two tables;

1. trips

| id | date | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2020 | 5000 |
| 2 | 01/01/2020 | 3000 |
| 3 | 02/01/2020 | 4000 |
| 4 | 02/01/2020 | 2000 |

2. expenses

| id | tripid | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 500 |
| 2 | 1 | 300 |
| 3 | 2 | 400 |
| 4 | 2 | 200 |
| 5 | 2 | 700 |

I would like to get the sum of revenue collected in a day AND sum of expenses in a day. I have the following sql which gives me results but the sums are entirely wrong.

`SELECT i.id, sum(i.revenue) as total, i.date trip , sum(c.amount) as exp, c.tripid expenses   FROM trip i INNER JOIN expenses c ON i.id = c.tripid GROUP BY i.date   ORDER BY trip  DESC`

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can preaggregate the expenses by trip, and then aggregate again in the outer query:

```
select t.date, sum(t.revenue) as revenue, coalesce(sum(e.expense), 0) as expense
from trips t
left join (
    select tripid, sum(amount) as expense
    from expenses
    group by tripid
) e on e.tripid = t.id
group by t.date
```